# #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax

Tags: mysql, sql

SQL query i'm running in phpMyAdmin :

```
INSERT INTO `companies`(`companyId`, `companyName`, `companyImage`)
    VALUES ([1],[Example Company],[image.jpg])
```

phpMyAdmin generates this, i'm just changing the values.

SQL database:

```
1   companyId int(100)

2   companyName varchar(100)    

3   companyImage varchar(100)
```

Error I get:

> #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '[1],[Example Company],[image.jpg])' at line 1

Comment: btw why are you saving brackets in db? maybe you are not as you said phpmyadmin generates it

Answer (score 1):

Use quotes, not brackets, around strings.  Integers and floats don't require anything but MySQL allows quotes around those as well.

Answer (score 0):

```
INSERT INTO `companies`(`companyId`, `companyName`, `companyImage`)
VALUES (1, 'Example Company', 'image.jpg')
```

Use backticks to escape column and table name.
Use quotes to limit strings.
Use nothing to limit numbers.
Don't use brackets at all in MySQL.